# ros2 humble cannot build custom messages or services

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to compile multiple packages in ros2 humble. I am trying to compile the ackerman messages [package](https://github.com/ros-drivers/ackermann_msgs/tree/ros2) as well as the franka ros2 [meta-package](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros2) (more specifically, the franka_msgs package). I see that there are custom messages and services involved. I followed the instructions to build the franka package. I also simply cloned the ackerman package into my ros 2 workspace like any other package. Both return this same error:

```sh
--- stderr: ackermann_msgs                                                                                                                                                                            
gmake[1]: *** No rule to make target 'ackermann_msgs__py/CMakeFiles/ackermann_msgs__py.dir/all', needed by 'CMakeFiles/ackermann_msgs__rosidl_generator_py.dir/all'.  Stop.
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
```

I looked in the cmake files and they both appear to create messages correctly. I saw that there were changes recently from Foxy to Humble, but I don't see how they are major breaking changes. It may be that I simply don't understand how to compile messages in Humble. How do you compile custom messages and services (and actions too) in ROS2 Humble?
Here are some resources I have referenced:

```
https://answers.ros.org/question/390451/colcon-build-fails-on-anything-with-messages-now-after-ubuntu-2004-foxy-sudo-apt-upgrade/
https://answers.ros.org/question/401345/ros2-humble-unable-to-compile-custom-srv-which-depends-on-msg/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71970577/ros2-custom-messages-build-failed-with-invalidfielddefinition
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23171/creating-a-custom-msg-in-ros2
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to compile these from source instead of using the released packages from the Build Farm (aka `apt` packages)?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Humble Release Notes](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Releases/Release-Humble-Hawksbill.html) it is stated that `rosidl_target_interfaces()` is deprecated and should be instead used `rosidl_get_typesupport_target()` and then `target_link_libraries()`.

To build the package you can use the following modified CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(ackermann_msgs)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/AckermannDrive.msg"
  "msg/AckermannDriveStamped.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
  ADD_LINTER_TESTS
)

rosidl_get_typesupport_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_typesupport_c
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/AckermannDrive"
  "msg/AckermannDriveStamped"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()
```