# [ROS2] Configure a Package having IDL files (srv, msg etc.) along with CPP

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to configure a package that contains srv, msg, etc., files along with CPP. However, the compiler can not find generated files. Below is the complete error:

```
ravi@dell:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --allow-overriding action_tutorials_cpp
Starting >>> action_tutorials_cpp
--- stderr: action_tutorials_cpp                             
/home/ravi/ros2_ws/src/action_tutorials_cpp/src/fibonacci_action_server.cpp:17:10: fatal error: action_tutorials_cpp/action/fibonacci.hpp: No such file or directory
   17 | #include "action_tutorials_cpp/action/fibonacci.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/action_tutorials.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/action_tutorials.dir/src/fibonacci_action_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:152: CMakeFiles/action_tutorials.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< action_tutorials_cpp [0.68s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.84s]
  1 package failed: action_tutorials_cpp
  1 package had stderr output: action_tutorials_cpp
```

Please note that, the *colcon* was able to generate header file successfully, as shown below:

```
ravi@dell:~/ros2_ws$ find . -name fibonacci.hpp
./build/action_tutorials_cpp/rosidl_generator_cpp/action_tutorials_cpp/action/fibonacci.hpp
```

Surprisingly, the *local_setup.bash* shows the following error:

```
ravi@dell:~/ros2_ws$ source install/local_setup.bash
not found: "/home/ravi/ros2_ws/install/action_tutorials_cpp/share/action_tutorials_cpp/local_setup.bash"
```

Please see an example below (merged from [action_tutorials_interfaces](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/foxy/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_interfaces) and [action_tutorials_cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/foxy/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_cpp)):

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(action_tutorials_cpp)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_action REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_components REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "action/Fibonacci.action")

include_directories(include)

add_library(action_tutorials SHARED
  src/fibonacci_action_server.cpp)
rclcpp_components_register_node(action_tutorials PLUGIN "action_tutorials_cpp::FibonacciActionServer" 
  EXECUTABLE fibonacci_action_server)
target_compile_definitions(action_tutorials
  PRIVATE "ACTION_TUTORIALS_CPP_BUILDING_DLL")
ament_target_dependencies(action_tutorials
  "rclcpp"
  "rclcpp_action"
  "rclcpp_components")

install(TARGETS
  action_tutorials
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>action_tutorials_cpp</name>
  <version>0.9.3</version>
  <description>C++ action tutorial cpp code</description>
  <maintainer email="mabel@openrobotics.org">Mabel Zhang</maintainer>
  <maintainer email="michael.jeronimo@openrobotics.org">Michael Jeronimo</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>
  <author email="jacob@openrobotics.org">Jacob Perron</author>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp_action</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp_components</depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

**CPP (head only)**

```
#include "action_tutorials_cpp/action/fibonacci.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "action_tutorials_cpp/visibility_control.h"
#include "rclcpp_action/rclcpp_action.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_components/register_node_macro.hpp"

namespace action_tutorials_cpp {
class FibonacciActionServer : public rclcpp::Node {
 public:
  using Fibonacci = action_tutorials_cpp::action::Fibonacci;
  using GoalHandleFibonacci = rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<Fibonacci>;

  ACTION_TUTORIALS_CPP_PUBLIC
  explicit FibonacciActionServer(
      const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options = rclcpp::NodeOptions())
      : Node("fibonacci_action_server", options) {
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    this->action_server_ = rclcpp_action::create_server<Fibonacci>(
        this->get_node_base_interface(), this->get_node_clock_interface(),
        this->get_node_logging_interface(),
        this->get_node_waitables_interface(), "fibonacci",
        std::bind(&FibonacciActionServer::handle_goal, this, _1, _2),
        std::bind(&FibonacciActionServer::handle_cancel, this, _1),
        std::bind(&FibonacciActionServer::handle_accepted, this, _1));
  }
```

**Package Structure**

```
└── action_tutorials_cpp
    ├── action
    │   └── Fibonacci.action
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── action_tutorials_cpp
    │       └── visibility_control.h
    ├── package.xml
    └── src
        └── fibonacci_action_server.cpp

5 directories, 5 files
```

**I want to know how to configure such a package in ROS2.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402196/%5Bros2%5D-configure-a-package-having-idl-files-(srv,-msg-etc.)-along-with-cpp/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2022-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to have msg/action/srv files in the same package as where you are using them, but the CMakeLists.txt is slightly different to the case where they are in separate packages.

The [Expanding on ROS Interfaces (Foxy)](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html) covers this exact case.

Modify your `CMakeLists.txt` as following:

```
// Your existing code
install(TARGETS
  action_tutorials
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

// ---- Insert Folowing ----

// Humble onwards
rosidl_get_typesupport_target(cpp_typesupport_target ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")
target_link_libraries(action_tutorials "${cpp_typesupport_target}")

// Foxy, Galactic
rosidl_target_interfaces(action_tutorials ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")

// ---- Up to here ----

// Your existing code
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
```

---

For more info, see this solution:

[Creating a custom msg in ros2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23171/creating-a-custom-msg-in-ros2)

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-06-12**:
Sweet and simple. The compilation error has gone! On a side note, I must say that ROS2 documentation is a bit difficult to follow. However, I hope, over time, the documentation (and API also) gets easier to find. Finger crossed.